# Assign object to variable in javascript (React) on two 2 conditions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  const router = useRouter();
  const { locale } = router;

  const featureId = props.id;
  let featureContent;
  
  featureContent =
    locale === "en"
      ? featureContentEn
      : locale === "de"
      ? featureContentDe
      : locale === "fr"
      ? featureContentFr
      : locale === "es"
      ? featureContentEs
      : locale === "ru"
      ? featureContentRu
      : featureContentEn;
```

So basically right now I am assigning featureContent to another object containing the actual content, conditionally according to the language of the router. But now there are three different versions of content that might appear, so the would be three variations of featureId (option1, option2, option3). So how could I combine this with the language condition?

Also I had the idea that I could put the three variations in to one general object with three nested objects and then passing the featureId to the object here with the brackets notation to use that object then so `featureContent[featureId]` <- would be a nested object with the according feature content. Would this be a good idea, or is there a better solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use an object

```
const locales = {
  en: featureContentEn,
  de: featureContentDe,
  fr: featureContentFr,
  es: featureContentEs,
  ru: featureContentRu
}

const featureContent = locales[locale] ?? featureContentEn
```